# I submitted my paper in a hijacked journal

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, publishers

I encountered a huge problem, I submited my paper in a [faked journal](http://www.mehrdadjalalian.com/index.php/updates-of-hijacked-journals/22-journal-ciencia-e-tecnica-vitivinicola-is-hijacked). I sent them several times about the result of reviewing process. The email answer was:

> Dear Author
>   Please clarify what exactly is your problem regarding your paper.
>   We are at your service and ready to assist.
>
> Regards 
>   Ciencia e Tecnica Vitivinicola Journal Editorial

They told me also if I have submitted successfully I will get the review answer at most after 2 weeks, but I have the proof of a successful submitted paper. Now what should I do? I want to resubmit it in another journal, I have an examination in the summer and I need a published paper in my resume.

Comment: So, do you want to withdraw your submission, or do you want them to perform a honest peer review process? Could you please clarify this in the question text?

Comment: i did not receive till now any notification for acceptance or rejection, should i wait or should i submit it in another journal ??

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly from your link, the journal exists and is legitimate, but you submitted your manuscript to a fake website falsely claiming to be the journal's website.

In this case, the proper things to do in my view are:

- **E-mail the editor in chief**. Do not simply resubmit with a cover letter explaining what happened: you don't know if and when they are going to read it. You want them to know immediately, and take action quickly.
- if you have the opportunity, **publish a preprint**. You should consider your manuscript as leaked and no longer private, and it is very likely that it is being sold or submitted somewhere else by the hackers. If the journal normally wouldn't allow a preprint, discuss it with the editor and see if they are willing to make an exception.
- If you paid something for the submission, go through the usual procedure for getting your money back: **block the credit card payment** and inquire with your bank, and contact the authorities to report theft.

Comment: http://ciencia-e-tecnica.org/ this is the link of journal, they told me that i should receive the notification after 12 days if i submitted successfully, but till now i did not receive any think, if i ask them they resend to me the same answer  

    Dear Author
    Please clarify what exactly is your problem regarding your paper.
    We are at your service and ready to assist.

    Regards Ciencia e Tecnica Vitivinicola Journal Editorial
and this is my question

Comment: dear Editor, i submitted my paper since November, i did not receive any notification till now, should i consider it as a rejected paper??

Comment: Your link says: *Ciencia e tecnica vitivinicola (ISSN: 0254-0223) is hijacked by cyber criminals. 
Counterfeit website: http://www.ciencia-e-tecnica.org 
Legitimate journal: http://www.scielo.oces.mctes.pt/scielo.php?script=sci_issues&pid=0254-0223&lng=en&nrm=iso* This contradicts your comment.

Comment: So, what's the solution? i did not receive any notification, should i submitted to another journal with changing the title ??

Comment: I wrote an email to the editor of facked journal, i inform his that i delete my submission and i will submit it to another journal, i already choose a journal, is it correct what i did it ??

Comment: Just make sure you contact the right people. If the content of your link is correct, you can't trust anything that comes from the site ciencia-e-tecnica.org.